# Segmentation fault (core dumped) while using scp in bash shell

Tags: linux, bash, stack-overflow, scp

I have a large number of .jpeg files that need to be transferred to a remote server. The remote server is a Digital Ocean droplet and I'm on Windows 10. I'm using the Git bash shell.

When I use this code (below) to transfer my files using `scp` (username and IP address changed for the sake of privacy).

```
donald@computer MINGW64 ~/Desktop/RETS Media/extra-large-photos
$ scp -r ./*.jpeg upload@192.199.99.100:/root/srep-3.1.1/dist/assets/extra-large-photos/
```

It returns this error message:

```
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

It also creates a file named scp.exe.stackdump. Here are the contents of that file:

```
Exception: STATUS_STACK_OVERFLOW at rip=001801DC8B6
rax=00000000002FCBF0 rbx=000000018030B570 rcx=00000000FFE03C40
rdx=00000001801FEA40 rsi=000000018030BEC0 rdi=00000000FFFFCDF0
r8 =00000001801FEA42 r9 =0000000000000000 r10=00000001802DFEA0
r11=00000001802E0068 r12=0000000000000000 r13=0000000000000000
r14=0000000000000000 r15=0000000000000000
rbp=00000000FFFFCCC0 rsp=00000000FFFFCC28
program=C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\scp.exe, pid 18872, thread unknown (0x18A4)
cs=0033 ds=002B es=002B fs=0053 gs=002B ss=002B
Stack trace:
Frame        Function    Args
000FFFFCCC0  001801DC8B6 (001800479BE, 00180046A70, 0010040D060, 001801F57E0)
000FFFFCCC0  000004F4BF0 (00180046A70, 0010040D060, 001801F57E0, 00000000000)
000FFFFCCC0  30001000000FF00 (0010040D060, 001801F57E0, 00000000000, 00000000000)
000FFFFCCC0  001800479BE (00000000000, 00000000000, 00000000000, 00000000000)
00000000000  00180045753 (00000000000, 00000000000, 00000000000, 00000000000)
000FFFFFFF0  00180045804 (00000000000, 00000000000, 00000000000, 00000000000)
End of stack trace
```

The error is literally a "Stack Overflow."

This is not a joke. 
I'm not trying to troll anyone.
This is a serious issue. 
I have to fix this.

So, where do I go from here?

Comment: The problem (whatever it is) is in your `scp.exe` and has nothing to do with bash

Comment: You are doing a star expansion, so how many files are in that directory?  How many files in total?

Comment: Maybe try creating a tar ball of the directory and then just scp'ing the one tar file.  Then just untar it on the other side.

Comment: @xxfelixxx A lot. about 300,000 extra-large .jpeg files. By extra-large, I mean like 800px x 600px.

Comment: @xxfelixx I've never used a tar ball before. Do you know of any good documentation?

Comment: @xxfelixxx I'm trying your suggestion right now.

Comment: @xxfelixxx I think it's working.

Comment: Create a tarball: `tar -czvf tarball.tar.gz /some/directory/` Unpack a tarball: `tar -xzvf tarball.tar.gz`  The `-z` flag gzips the resulting tarball to make it smaller.

Comment: You can use the following commands if available on your machine: `find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '*.jpg' | xargs -n10 -I {} scp -r {} upload@192.199.99.100:/root/srep-3.1.1/dist/assets/extra-large-photos/` otherwise go for the tarball or `rsync`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not make a star expansion on a "large amount of jpeg files" in `MSYS` or `MINGW` systems. This can lead to some serious trouble.

I would suggest creating a tarball of the files using the `tar` command or a `zip` file (if you prefer that, but when packing `jpeg` files together another compression like `zip` or `gzip` is unneccessary, will use up CPU and will not result in smaller files as `jpeg` files are already compressed).

I suggest for documentation purposes you can read the manpage of `tar` here: https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/1-tar/

For example to compress a folder called `photos` with your files in it, do this:

```
tar -cf photos.tar photos
```

which will create the file `photos.tar`. You can transfer this file via `scp`.

What works unter Linux and **should** work on MSYS if you are working in bash and not cmd is directly writing to `stdout` with tar, transfer it via `ssh` (not `scp`) and uncompress it directly on the other end again:

```
tar -cf - photos/ | ssh youruser@yourserver.com tar -xf - -C ~/
```

This will uncompress the files to your homedir. If you want to add compression (which I still do not recommend in this case) you can use `czf` and `xzf` in both tar command.

Comment: Thank you! To be completely honest, I'm using a Git bash shell on Windows 10 (I apologize for not being so specific). I will come back to this as I am trying to compress the folder itself into a tar.gz file and Windows doesn't allow much more than one program to access a directory at a time. I'm going to try to scp it over to the remote server and then untar it on the other end. But I will get back to you!

Comment: then the second variant should work in git bash. also do not use compression. it just uses up CPU like stated in the answer. JPEG is already compressed and compression will not do anything. Just use tar, it simply puts the files one after another to a file. Also if you use the second method you will not have to deal with a temporary file...

Comment: Ah. I see! So I can pipe it to ssh. Okay. Give me just a minute. Let me try that.

Comment: This is what I got:

$ tar - cf extra-large-photos/ | ssh upload@198.199.99.100 tar xf - -C ~/path/to/extra-large-photos/
tar: You must specify one of the '-Acdtrux', '--delete' or '--test-label' options
Try 'tar --help' or 'tar --usage' for more information.
upload@198.199.99.100's password:
tar: This does not look like a tar archive
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors

Comment: okay seems like the binary of `tar` is a bit older on windows :). Use `tar -cf - photos/` and `tar -xf - -C ~/` (note the extra `-`). Edited the answer to contain that.

Comment: `tar -cf - photos/` returns this:
tar: Refusing to write archive contents to terminal (missing -f option?)
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now

Comment: Okay, so I realized you mean to pipe it. I tried that. It thought that I was referring to my local machine when I used ~ so it said "No such file or directory" which is fine, so I replace ~/ with my username /upload/. Now, I've run this and after I put my password in, it just stopped. I'm guessing that's because I didn't use the -v flag.

Comment: That command only works when piped. When using -v you will get some informations about the progress (but note that stuff also gets buffered, so you cannot rely 100% on that). If you want better progress use `rsync` over ssh.

Comment: This is the answer! I wish I could give you more than just a few points for this because you've **really** helped me *when it counted!*